# How do I add the values in Java that are inside JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, project

I'm doing a project given from my school i have to make the bill printing program like the ones in department store i have connected it with MySQL successfully the product and price is also shown in the `JTable` but I don't know how to add the price of those product (*i do know how to add normally by putting the number in `JTextField` but never done inside a table*). And I also need to discount 5% on membership with `JCheckBox` that will be directly shown on the total `JTextField`.

[Department Store project layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xoys.png)

Comment: *"Department Store project layout"* A screen shot of the GUI adds nothing to the question worth knowing. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the method `getValueAt(int row_index, int col_index)` This method returns the object at specified row and column position. It takes the following arguments:

`row_index`: This is the index of row, whose value has to be retrieved.

`col_index`: This is the index of column, whose value has to be retrieved.

Take a look into this : [Getting Cell values in a JTable](https://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/GetCellValues.shtml)